# Seamless Responsive Marquee Effect with JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, marquee

Hey there I am trying to implement a seamless marquee effect. Here is the example I am trying to accomplish.
https://dentripelantwerpen.cargo.site/

So far I have this:

https://rubi-rosa.de/home/

```
<div class="inner-content">
    <div class="outer-div">
      <div class="inner-container">
        <h1>&nbsp;DEN TRIPEL<br></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="inner-container2">
        <h1>&nbsp;DEN TRIPEL<br></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css

```
.inner-content {
width:100%;
height:100vh;
}


.outer-div {
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

.inner-container {
animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}

.inner-container2 {
animation: marquee2 10s linear infinite; 
animation-delay: 5s;
}

 @keyframes marquee {
    from {transform: translateX(100%); }
    to {transform: translateX(-100%); }
     
     
 @keyframes marquee2 {
    from {transform: translateX(0%); }
    to {transform: translateX(-200%); }
```

I tried many approaches I found on the web. And came to the conclusion that I have to use to divs which will transform in and out of the viewport. But somehow only one of them is displaying. I would love to have such a smooth animation as in the example linked on top. Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I retract my answer. Went back and looked and it's wonky. I'll come back if I get a chance.

You'll be able to get what you want without js. I removed a bunch of what I felt was unnecessary html.

Because you're animating two things that need to respect each other's **position** what I did was position them absolutely and your stuff worked fine. I added some stuff to show the different two elements and my looping is a bit off (I gotta run because of work stuff). Check out the pen to see what I mean. You'll have to tweak things and do a better job visually but the function is there. You were really close.

```
h1 {
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 650px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.first {
  color: green
}
.second {
  left: 900px;
  color: blue
}
```

https://codepen.io/christopherpenny/pen/VwyvyXm